# Application startup fail for weblogic restart and success for second time. (With differen openjpa metada)

Tags: java, classloader, openjpa, weblogic-10.x

it's difficult to describe case so below short case and result of my investigation:

Environment:

- java 1.6
- weblogic-10.3.6.0
- openjpa - 1.1.0
- spring - 3.2
- Two persistence-unit in one persistence.xml (A and R)

Case:

1. Deploy war file to weblogic is successful
2. Stop app in admin console
3. Try start app - it's  Failed
4. Try start again - it's success!

stacktrace

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException:Table "ACTION_COMMENT" given for "......ActionComment" does not exist.
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo.createTable(MappingInfo.java:470)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMappingInfo.getTable(ClassMappingInfo.java:229)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.FullClassStrategy.map(FullClassStrategy.java:71)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.setStrategy(ClassMapping.java:381)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:55)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:318)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:667)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:549)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:308)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.<init>(PCEnhancer.java:248)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.<init>(PCEnhancer.java:219)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.<init>(PCEnhancer.java:187)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:121)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:310)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:228)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:190)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:145)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:445)
```

Investigation:

Failed case:
It's happen because ActionComment should be save in persistence-unit **R**, but jpa in **MappingInfo** try to find it in  persistence-unit **A**. 
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo line 466 
`Table table = group.findTable(fullName);` group is org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.LazySchemaFactory then in line 140 
`_conn = _conf.getDataSource2(null).getConnection();` return connection to persistence-unit **A**.
Successful case: 
Stacktrace is different! Different behavior in org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory processing block from line 281 to 287

```
                Collection c = new ArrayList(clss.size());
            for (Iterator itr = clss.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                Class cls = (Class) itr.next();
                c.add(cls.getName());
                if (needsSub(cls))
                    toRedefine.add(cls);
            }
```

In successful case result of this code block **toRedefine** collection is empty and code below (line 310 in AbstractBrokerFactory ) 
`// get the ManagedClassSubclasser into the loop
        ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(
            _conf, toRedefine, envLoader)` don't have any effect.

**needsSub(cls)**

```
    private boolean needsSub(Class cls) {
    return !cls.isInterface()
        && !PersistenceCapable.class.isAssignableFrom(cls);
}
```

For first restart (failed case) `PersistenceCapable.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)` return **false** and all method return true.
For second restart (success case) `PersistenceCapable.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)` return **true** and all method return false.
In **cls** ActionComment class, result of getClassLoader() call.

Failure case:

```
result = {weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@26293}"weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@fa3e780 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@4ce80175 annotation: svwi@svwi-2.9.1-SHAPSHOT.war"
```

Success case

```
result = {weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@29327}"weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@3932d2a2 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@44e8cb1e annotation: svwi@svwi-2.9.1-SHAPSHOT.war"
```

Could anybody help with it?

**Update**
persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="analysys" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <jta-data-source>AnalysisDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>.....Rule</class>
      ...other classes..

    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ManagedRuntime" value="org.apache.openjpa.ee.JNDIManagedRuntime" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties"
            value="PrintParameters=true, PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72" />

         <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.DetachState"
            value="loaded(DetachedStateField=true, DetachedStateManager=true)" />
        <property name="openjpa.IgnoreChanges" value="true" />
         <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="reaction" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <jta-data-source>ReactionDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>.....ActionComment</class>
    ...other classes..

    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ManagedRuntime" value="org.apache.openjpa.ee.JNDIManagedRuntime" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties"
            value="PrintParameters=true, PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72" />
         <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.DetachState"
            value="loaded(DetachedStateField=true, DetachedStateManager=true)" />
        <property name="openjpa.IgnoreChanges" value="true" />
         <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Post the contents of your persistence.xml file.

Comment: Apparently this should go to the OpenJPA bugtracking system as a bug report.